# Simultaneously extracting list of dimensions and creating scale for each in d3.js - Expand on process?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As a beginner of D3 I'd like to know more about whats going on in this command step by step. Please help me understand how the lists are formed and how they are prescribed individual scales using the command.

Can this command be broken up into separate blocks?
- such as one for list creation, and another for yAxis definition

```
   var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width], 1),
   y = {};

  // Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
  x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
    return d != "name" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
        .range([height, 0]));
  }));
```

Data for this is

```
name,economy (mpg),cylinders,displacement (cc),power (hp),weight (lb),0-60 mph (s),year
AMC Ambassador Brougham,13,8,360,175,3821,11,73
AMC Ambassador DPL,15,8,390,190,3850,8.5,70
AMC Ambassador SST,17,8,304,150,3672,11.5,72
```

Source: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1341021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very elegant way to create an object named `y` with several different linear scales, one for each categorical variable in the `x`axis (since we're dealing with a parallel coordinates chart).

Here is the logic:

First, Bostock (the author of that code) declares an ordinal scale for the `x` axis...

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width], 1)
```

... and an empty object:

```
var y = {}
```

So far, nothing unusual.

Then we get to the block that puzzled you. Let's break it up.

It defines the domain of the `x` scale, at the same time that creates a global named `dimensions`:

```
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
    return d != "name"
}));
```

`dimensions` is in fact just an array of strings...

```
["economy (mpg)",
    "cylinders",
    "displacement (cc)",
    "power (hp)",
    "weight (lb)",
    "0-60 mph (s)",
    "year"
]
```

... made with `d3.keys(cars[0])`, filtering out the `name` column.

However, inside the filter function, it is populating the `y` object:

```
y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) {
        return +p[d];
    }))
    .range([height, 0]);
```

For every column (that is, every value in `dimensions` array), except `name`, it's creating an scale (since `false && anything` is short-circuit evaluated to `false`, and the `anything` part is just ignored, there will be no `y` scale for the `name` column).

So, if `d` in one particular iteration is `cylinders`, it will create this property in the `y` object:

```
y["cylinders"] = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) {
        return +p["cylinders"];
    }))
    .range([height, 0]))
```

At the end, if you `console.log(y)`, you're gonna see an object with all the scales, like this (my ridiculous attempt to imitate the Chrome console):

```
> Object
    > 0 - 60 mph(s): u(n)
    > cylinders: u(n)
    > displacement(cc): u(n)
    > economy(mpg): u(n)
    > power(hp): u(n)
    > weight(lb): u(n)
    > year: u(n)
    > __proto__: Object
```

**Post Scriptum**: a mere mortal, like me, would write that code in a much more humble way:

```
dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
    return d != "name";
});

x.domain(dimensions);

dimensions.forEach(function(d) {
    y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) {
            return +p[d];
        }))
        .range([height, 0])
})
```

And the result is the same. Here is the bl.ocks to show it: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/87b926c85b8385aecdab722c74c4d2ef

Comment: BTW, you missed out on the `&&` operator which also has a crucial role in the statement. Incorporating this would make it a really great answer!

Comment: I didn't missed it, it's already in the answer: *"For every column (that is, every value in dimensions array), except 'name', he's creating an scale"*. But I'll edit to make it even clearer.

Comment: Not related: this question uses `d3.js-v4` tag, which should be remapped to `d3.js`. We need just one more vote to remap it: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/d3.js/synonyms

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you for pointing this out. I searched for the the v3 tag, but it doesn't seem to exists in as an auto populate.

Comment: Yes, there is no v3 tag, and there should be no v4 tag. That was discussed on meta: all questions should be tagged with `d3.js` only, and any problem specifically related to a given version should be detailed in the question itself.

Comment: Since that code is using D3 v3.x, just remove the `d3.js-v4` tag.

Comment: After I shared the link to the synonyms, someone went there and **voted down** the proposal to merge the tags... Oh, democracy, what's wrong with you?